# Making signed HTTP requests to Twitter's REST API v1.1 from Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth, parse-platform

This question has been reformatted and resubmitted.

## [Go here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654245/how-to-correctly-sign-an-http-request-to-twitters-rest-api-v1-1-in-nodejs)

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar using Parse Cloud Code, would you mind sharing your cloud/main.js file? Links are broke :) @aleclarson

Comment: @ryder [Try this link.](https://gist.github.com/aleclarson/8892714)