# How to correctly sign an HTTP request to Twitter's REST API v1.1 in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, oauth, parse-platform

I'm only getting error 32 "Could not authenticate you" when I call `twitter.request()` ([defined in my cloud/twitter.js file](https://gist.github.com/aleclarson/8892714)) inside [Parse Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide). I've done everything Twitter told me to do in ["Creating a Signature"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature) and ["Authorizing a request"](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) at [dev.twitter.com](https://dev.twitter.com/), but I cannot seem to find how to do so.

**Has anyone else had experience with accessing the Twitter REST API v1.1 using Parse Cloud Code?**

**P.S.** You can assume I have the user's "access token" and "token secret" in a `Parse.User` as `twitterToken` and `twitterTokenSecret`, but I have also provided `ACCESS_TOKEN` and `TOKEN_SECRET` constants so you don't have to recreate my `Parse.User` to help me debug this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an easy fix (thankfully). The problem lied in a `&` trailing my signature (facepalm). Here's the function I had to change.

```
function getAuthSignature (user, request, oauth) {
  var signingKey, body, signatureBase;

  signingKey =
    ENCODING_METHOD(CONSUMER_SECRET) + '&' + ENCODING_METHOD(TOKEN_SECRET);

  body = 
    mapObject(oauth, ampersandEncoding)
    .concat(mapObject(request.params, ampersandEncoding))
    .sort();

  // Remove trailing ampersand. (aka the fix)
  body.push(body.pop().replace('&', ''));

  signatureBase =
    request.method.toUpperCase() + '&' +
    ENCODING_METHOD(request.url) + '&' +
    ENCODING_METHOD(body.join(''));

  return crypto.createHmac('sha1', signingKey)
               .update(signatureBase)
               .digest('base64');
};
```